# How to start up with jQuery in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I know C# really well, just started playing with ASP.Net MVC a few weeks ago, and almost zero javascript. I saw some people here recomending jQuery, so I'll try that out.

What resources/tutorial should I start with?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go straight from the source:

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

You may want to see

http://www.w3schools.com/JS/default.asp

Answer (score 1):

[Learning jQuery](http://www.learningjquery.com) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery site has excellent documentation and lots of samples. It really is the best place to get started.

For general JavaScript I would read [JavaScript The Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748/)

Answer (score 1):

Try checking out Rob Conery's blog post, [Putting the M back in MVC](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2009/03/31/putting-the-ldquo-m-rdquo-back-in-mvc).  It integrates a pre version 3 of Subsonic, ASP.Net MVC, and jQuery(core, UI, and forms). It's quick and easy to build simple web applications.  It will move you up the jQuery learning curve fairly quickly if you are looking at Ajax, forms validation, and some basic CSS twiddling.

The nice thing about this approach is you get working applications that allow you to try different approaches.